# Problems in accessing questions from mobile web site after installation of the SE app

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-web

I have recently installed the SE Android App, and to use both the mobile Web and the App as both have features unique to them.

However, after installing the app, when I click on a question in the question list in any network site, then the question doest open up at the first attempt. I have to click on the question title again to open it. The [screen video](https://youtu.be/CuKHDLrWoIg) shows this bug in Physics SE, but it is similary relevant in all network sites.

If I uninstall the app, this problem stops.

What is the cause of this, and how can it be prevented? I've tried clearing chrome browsing history and site storage, but with no success.